# QImage loadFromData doesn't load the data of my images

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I'm new to Qt and I have been trying to develop a simple video streaming application.

While developing my app, I've been facing a problem I thought could be ignored at first, but that's not the case. In fact, this problem is slowing down my whole application and is making it not working.

Here's my problem: When I'm trying to display many images I have 2 choices:

1. Using the QImage constructor QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, QImage::Format format) to construct the image and display it. It's working as intended but is VERY, VERY slow
2. Or load the data of the images with QImage::loadFromData(uchar *, int len), which is simply not working.

Here's my working code:

```
void MainWindow::startCapturing()
{
  timer->start();
  // on press of a button, the timer will call repeatedly the generateImage() function
}

void MainWindow::generateImage()
{
  det->GetImage(&image);    // fulfill my image with data

  myImage=QImage((uchar*)image.GetValuePointer(),image.GetSize().height,image.GetSize().width, 
  QImage::Format_Grayscale16);
  // here GetValuePointer returns a void *, that's why we had to cast it.

  ui->img_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
}
```

Here's my not working code

```
void MainWindow::startCapturing2()
{
   
  myImage=QImage((uchar*)image.GetValuePointer(),image.GetSize().height,image.GetSize().width, 
  QImage::Format_Grayscale16);

  ui->img_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
  timer->start();
  // on press of a button, the timer will call repeatedly the generateImage() function
}

void MainWindow::generateImage2()
{
   det->GetImage(&image);

   myImage.loadFromData((uchar *)image.GetValuePointer(), image.GetSizeInBytes());
   // same cast of GetValuePointer as above

   ui->img_label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
}
```

INFORMATIONS ABOUT THE CODE:

- det->GetImage(&image) fulfill my Image object named image here.
- Image is my own type because I'm working with specific cameras and had to do so, it's more on the hardware side, don't bother with that.
- image.GetValuePointer() returns the data of the image as a void * to be cast in anything you want.
- don't bother with timer() and startCapturing() as well, it's working, that's not the point of the topic.
- in StartCapturing2, I'm trying to create the QImage, and set the pixmap so that if I update myImage with loadFromData, it will change the image displayed.

I've been trying many things, like a lot of them, using a QByteArray for example but it's either not working or simply not what I want.

If you have any question, please ask them I will try to answer as fast and best as I can! Thanks!

Comment: You haven't provided any value for `format` parameter for [`loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData) (default value is `nullptr`) so most likely QImage tries to find a image header, doesn't find any and gives up, not being able to handle the following data.

Comment: Also, the second option might be even slower than the first because it copies the data while the first one uses the existing data from `image`. See [constructor documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-4)

Comment: Oh okay yeah I missed the format, but it's a const char * param and not a QImage::Format so I don't really know what to put in it ? Like "GrayScale_16" or something like that ? Also, for the slowness I've kinda fixed it, it was coming from all an other thing that was accessing and updating my data and was not optimized. So I will try both solutions and choose the fastest one obviously. Anyways thanks for the answer !

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData : "using the specified format, e.g., PNG or JPG", and the link there to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files shows the possible values.

Comment: Yeah so definitly loadFromData isn"t what i need because none of these formats are the one that i want.  I'll use the constructor instead. Thanks you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any value for the `format` parameter for [`loadFromData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#loadFromData) (default value is `nullptr`) so most likely `QImage` tries to find a image header, doesn't find any and gives up, not being able to handle the following data.

> The loader attempts to read the image using the specified *format*, e.g., PNG or JPG. If *format* is not specified (which is the default), the loader probes the file for a header to guess the file format.

---

On a side note, your second option might be even slower than the first because it copies the data while the first one uses the existing data from image. See [constructor documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-4) (emphasis mine):

> ```cpp
> QImage::QImage(const uchar *data, int width, int height,
>                QImage::Format format,
>                QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = nullptr,
>                void *cleanupInfo = nullptr)
> ```
>
> Constructs an image [...] **that uses an existing read-only memory buffer, *data***.